# Set color to be used for an array masked values plotted with matplotlib contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

When I plot an array with masked values, using matplotlib `countourf`, the masked values appear white. I want them to appear grey.

I tried the `set_bad` method, but it seems `countourf` doesn't recognize it (although it recognizes the `set_over` and `set_under` methods).

Is there any other method I can use with `contourf`?

Or will I have to change my code to use `imshow`, which understands `set_bad`, instead of `countourf`?

Comment: For what it's worth, `contourf` and `contour` differ from `imshow` in that they simply don't draw anything where the array is masked.  They're not making the masked areas white, it's just the background of the plot showing through.  This is why they don't have a `set_bad` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting first the background, like:

```
x,y=meshgrid(linspace(0,1),linspace(0,1))
fig=plt.figure()
a=fig.add_subplot(111,axisbg='gray')
z=ma.masked_array(x**2-y**2,mask=y>-x+1)
a.contourf(z)
```

Comment: Knowing now that contourf simply doesn't draw anything where the array is masked, this will certainly work!