# hatch a NaN region in a contourplot in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, nan, contour

I am contourplotting a matrix of data. Some of the matrix's elements are NaN's (corresponding to parameter combinations where no solution exists). I would like to indicate this region in the contourplot by a hatched region. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selective patterns with Matplotlib imshow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045709/selective-patterns-with-matplotlib-imshow)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`contourf` and `contour`methods don't draw anything where an array is masked (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042932/set-color-to-be-used-for-an-array-masked-values-plotted-with-matplotlib-contourf))! So, if you want the NaN elements region of the plot to be hatched, you just have to define the background of the plot as hatched.

See this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# generate some data:
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1),np.linspace(0,1))
z = np.ma.masked_array(x**2-y**2,mask=y>-x+1)

# plot your masked array
ax.contourf(z)

# get data you will need to create a "background patch" to your plot
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
xy = (xmin,ymin)
width = xmax - xmin
height = ymax - ymin

# create the patch and place it in the back of countourf (zorder!)
p = patches.Rectangle(xy, width, height, hatch='/', fill=None, zorder=-10)
ax.add_patch(p)
plt.show()
```

You'll get this figure:
[image]